# Get Month & Day from Date

Tags: linux, unix, date

I am trying to get Month and Date from Date in Linux. this is my code

```
# Set Date 
D="2013/01/17"

# get day 
DD=$(D+"%d")

# get day 
MM=$(D+"%M")

# Day 
echo "Day:"$DD
echo "Month:"$MM
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In `sh` or `bash`:

```
D="2013/01/17"
DAY=$(date -d "$D" '+%d')
MONTH=$(date -d "$D" '+%m')
YEAR=$(date -d "$D" '+%Y')

echo "Day: $DAY"
echo "Month: $MONTH"
echo "Year: $YEAR"
```

Answer (score 25):

Or if you want the current date, use `date +%Y/%m/%d`. If you want them separately you can do something like this:

```
read YYYY MM DD <<<$(date +'%Y %m %d')
echo "Today is Day:$DD Month:$MM"
```

An easier approach is:

```
DD=$(date +%d)
MM=$(date +%m)
echo "Today is Day:$DD Month:$MM"
```

However in this case you're executing `date` twice, which is inefficient, and if you're really unlucky, the date could change between those two lines ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
kent$  D="2013/01/17"

kent$  awk -F/ '{print "year:"$1,"Month:"$2,"Day:"$3}'<<<$D
year:2013 Month:01 Day:17
```

if you want just Month or Day, just leave $2 or $3 there, delete the parts you don't need

Edit

```
kent$  year=$(awk -F/ '{print $1}' <<<$D)                                                                                                                                   

kent$  echo $year
2013
```

Comment: Kent , thanks can I store month year and day into variable. I am new to this . Thanks

Comment: @user1570210 sure you can. see Edit. I just made it with year. you should know how to deal with month or day. just change $1 to $2 or $3. good luck